# How set dynamic url param?

Tags: karate

Because my all case run by jenkins and I have the default url on `karate-config.js`.

But the jenkins job should support other url, so I want to pass the url address dynamic.

I know `env`, but I don't know how set it?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass it as a Java system property:

```
-D my.url=http://foo.bar
```

And in Karate:

```
var url = karate.properties['my.url'];
```

Please refer: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/547